# How do I use url-retrieve to update a hash map value in elisp?

Tags: elisp

I have a list of names that need to be validated through a web query. In order to do this manually I would enter a name into a search string, submit the string to the service, read the response and determine whether or not the name is valid. I am planning on performing this operation in batches of around 1000. My current struggle is retrieving the proper return value from the url-retrieve function.

```
(defvar *name-hash* (make-hash-table :test 'equal)) ;;Create Global Hash Table
(defun name-query (str)
  (let ((name-url "http://nameservice.com/x/namesearch?name=")
    (url-request-method "GET")
    (arg (url-hexify-string str))
    (retr-value (url-retrieve (concat name-url arg)      
                       (lambda (status)(switch-to-buffer (current-buffer))
                     (if (search-forward "</name>" nil t);; if search result for name tag
                         (retr-value "FOUND")            ;; then return value
                       (retr-value "AVAILABLE"))))))     ;; else return value 
    (puthash str retr-value *hostname-hash*)))           ;; populate hash table
```

Example call

```
(name-query "myname")
```

I expect the hash-table to be updated with a key-value pair similar to `("myname" "AVAILABLE")`. Instead the hash-value is updated with something similar to

`("myname" "#buffer    *http://nameservice.com/x/namesearch?name*-71829>")`

How do I carry the results of the anonymous function's `if` statement into the `puthash` function?

Answer (score 0):

Construct a better function. Let's look at the steps required to solve the problem. They are:

- declare a URL to call
- build the full URL and set the request method
- read the retrieved URL contents in a buffer
- move the pointer to the beginning of the URL content buffer
- search forward for a pattern (in my case an HTML tag works)
- return the appropriate value (in my case FOUND or AVAILABLE)
- update the hash map by setting the value equal to the if statement result

Below is elisp code that follows the above steps. In the original question I struggled with passing the name-query argument to the if statement. By moving the if statement up one level, the function's argument is available.

```
(defvar *name-hash* (make-hash-table :test 'equal)) ;;Create Global Hash Table    
(defun name-query (str)
      (let ((name-url "http://nameservice.com/x/namesearch?name=")
        (url-request-method "GET")
        (url (concat name-url (url-hexify-string str))))
        (let ((download-buffer (url-retrieve-synchronously url)))
          (save-excursion
        (set-buffer download-buffer)
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (if (search-forward "</hostname>" nil t)
            (setf (gethash str *hostname-hash*) "FOUND")
          (setf (gethash str *hostname-hash*) "AVAILABLE"))))))
```